# How to download bulk PDF files on demand using angular and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, html2pdf

I'm downloading PDF file using html2pdf library, but this downloads a single structure of PDF. Now I need to download 60-70 PDF's of different data(same structure), data of PDF is fetched on click from an API.

I'm bit confused how to achieve this. I think this will be done in backend stream process of generating all the 60 PDF's when user demands and the zipping all 60 files and then downloading it on frontend. Single PDF is downloading using this code, but it is not feasible to download 50-60 PDF on frontend.

```
var element = document.getElementById('healthcard');
var opt = {
   margin:3,
    filename:     `document.pdf`,
    image:        { type: 'jpg', quality: 0.98 },
    html2canvas:  { scale: 2, useCORS: true },
    jsPDF:        { unit: 'mm', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
};
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
```

It will be helpful if somebody shows me roadmap of how to achieve this, with optimized solution. Also putting those 50-60 PDF on server will not work as data changes frequently and it needs to be fetched on demand.

Comment: use can use file saver library https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: @ashishpal I know file-saver can be used for downloading PDF and zip files, but before downloading I need to generate those pdf files, and I don't know how to perform this task.

Comment: @mjwills I'm using C# as back-end language that's why i mentioned it.